# Hard disk in CD bay laptop not recognized

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, hardware-detection

I've replaced the optical disc drive on my laptop with a caddy and a Seagate SSHD. My laptop (HP ZBook 15G2) won't recognize this drive as a storage device. Windows explorer says that is is a BD-Rom drive.
Diskmanagement recognizes the disk, but initializing the disk gives an error 'in the I/O device'. The Seagate DiscWizzard won't recognize the disk.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of interface (plugs/connectors) are used?  What does the system firmware (BIOS / (U)EFI) report about the device?